Unreal Engine, EOS
Возникла проблема, сделан мультиплеер через EOS, движок 5.4
При подключении к сессии персонаж должен переноситься к владельцу сессии, коннект к сессии происходит, но переноса в мир нету, так как вылазит ошибка в логах:
LogEOSSDK: Error: LogEOSLobby: Invalid parameter EOS_Lobby_CopyLobbyDetailsHandleOptions.LocalUserId reason: is not a valid Product User ID, Result: EOS_InvalidUser

